# 'ClaimsIdentity.BootstrapContext' could not be mapped error when initialising database with test data

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am trying set up an Authorization server using IdentityServer4. I get the following errors when i try to run a piece of code to generate a test data. below is the code

```
private static void InitializeDbTestData(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();

            if (!context.Clients.Any())
            {
                foreach (var client in Clients.Get())
                {
                    context.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity());
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (!context.Scopes.Any())
            {
                foreach (var clientSope in Scopes.Get())
                {
                    context.Scopes.Add(clientSope.ToEntity());
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            if (!userManager.Users.Any())
            {
                foreach (var applicationUser in Users.Get())
                {
                    foreach (var claim in applicationUser.UserClaims)
                    {
                        //ExtendedClaimsProvider.CreateClaim()
                        applicationUser.Claims.Add(new IdentityUserClaim<Guid>
                        {
                            UserId = applicationUser.Id,
                            ClaimType = claim.Type,
                            ClaimValue = claim.Value,

                        });
                    }

                    userManager.CreateAsync(applicationUser, "Password123!").Wait();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is generated when

```
scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
```

is executed.

below is the error generated

```
 System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code  HResult=-2146233079  Message=The property 'ClaimsIdentity.BootstrapContext' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'object' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it.
```

Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.PropertyMappingValidationConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
       at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetTEntity
       at ReportBook.Auth.Startup.InitializeDbTestData(IApplicationBuilder app) in C:\Users\Julius\Documents\Projects\School\Development\ReportBook\ReportBook.Auth\Startup.cs:line 166
       at ReportBook.Auth.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in C:\Users\Julius\Documents\Projects\School\Development\ReportBook\ReportBook.Auth\Startup.cs:line 233
  InnerException:

The following is my startup class

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
        {
            // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
            builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
        }
        _environment = env;
        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration["Data:UserAccConnection:ConnectionString"];
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "reportbook.auth.pfx"), "");
        services.AddCors();

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));

        // Register the Identity services.
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, UserRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext, Guid>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddOperationalStore(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options => options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
            .AddConfigurationStore(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options => options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
            .SetSigningCredential(cert)
            .AddProfileService<IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>();

        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>();

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();


        //services.AddTransient<IDatabaseInitializer, DatabaseInitializer>();

     }
    private static void InitializeDbTestData(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();

            if (!context.Clients.Any())
            {
                foreach (var client in Clients.Get())
                {
                    context.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity());
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (!context.Scopes.Any())
            {
                foreach (var clientSope in Scopes.Get())
                {
                    context.Scopes.Add(clientSope.ToEntity());
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            if (!userManager.Users.Any())
            {
                foreach (var applicationUser in Users.Get())
                {
                    foreach (var claim in applicationUser.UserClaims)
                    {
                        //ExtendedClaimsProvider.CreateClaim()
                        applicationUser.Claims.Add(new IdentityUserClaim<Guid>
                        {
                            UserId = applicationUser.Id,
                            ClaimType = claim.Type,
                            ClaimValue = claim.Value,

                        });
                    }

                    userManager.CreateAsync(applicationUser, "Password123!").Wait();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod());

        app.UseExceptionHandler(
          builder =>
          {
              builder.Run(
                async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                    var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                });
          });

        app.UseCsp(options => options.DefaultSources(directive => directive.Self())
            .ImageSources(directive => directive.Self()
               .CustomSources("*"))
            .ScriptSources(directive => directive.Self()
                .UnsafeInline())
            .StyleSources(directive => directive.Self()
                .UnsafeInline()));

        app.UseXContentTypeOptions();
        app.UseXfo(options => options.Deny());
        app.UseXXssProtection(options => options.EnabledWithBlockMode());

        InitializeDbTestData(app);
        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        app.UseMvc();
        //databaseInitializer.Seed(app).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

}
```

I will appreciate any help

Comment: Your `UserDbContext` is what's throwing. It sounds like you're extending the ASP.NET Identity code, this is the code that has the issue and that people would need to see in order to help you further. The IdentityServer side of things is not the issue here.

Comment: @Scott Brady Yeah you are  right Ben Cull pointed it out to me. It turns out that the ApplicationUser Class has a property "Public ClaimsPrincipal UserClaims{get;set;}". This was generating the error. I deleted it out and everything worked fine. Here is the link "https://github.com/j-tee/ReportBook1/blob/57bb787da5d63055f9829d5c9d58e41cf8f0566e/ReportBook.Data/ApplicationUserInfo/ApplicationUser.cs#L34"